# iPad scrollable area

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am a complete novice to iPhone/iPad development, but I have OOP experience in other languages.  I apologize in advance if this question is rather vague.

What I really want to know is this:

My app idea needs to work in a single view where the view is a scrollable area that is a fixed height (bigger than the viewport).  Various different events can happen within this scrollable area.  The app will have an immersive feel to it (quite texture/image intensive), but it is not a 'game' as such (think scrollable bookshelf).

Which apple project would be a good way to start this? View-based? OpenGL ES?
How easy is it to make a fixed scrollable area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you describe making a simple UIKit app will suffice. You should start either a window or view based project.

Adding a fixed scrollable are is very easy using a UIScrollView.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html